# How to debug stored procedure query in code igniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-3

I want to debug a stored procedure query in code igniter model. Is there any tools available for debug this query?

I've tried printing the query, but it does not help.

My page is blank after I use the stored procedure with insert and update function in model.

```
$UpdateArray = array('Update', $fkCategoryGlCode, trim($varQuestion), trim($varAnswer), $intDisplayOrder, $chrPublish, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $updateid, @id); 
$query = $this->db->query("CALL Faq(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,@id)", $UpdateArray);
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: First off you have a different number of values in `$UpdateArray` than `?` in your query - probably remove `@id` from the array (not to mention it's not a string nor a variable, so that's likely where this is failing). Otherwise, I would start by first `var_dump`ing all of those variables to confirm they're the values you're expecting. Then I would try manually executing the query (with variable values hardcoded in) in the DB directly to make sure that works as expected.